# how can i pass image to another viewcontroller using storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I am using storyboard and xcode 5.

I am trying to use NSUserDefaults to store image data. But i have lots of image
I think this will exhaust quickly.
Is there any better way pass image data to another screen ??

Comment: Where are these images coming from? Are you storing them somewhere (e.g. in a cache or in "`Documents`") or are you loading them from a website or?

Comment: yes i am getting image data from website

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare a property in destination view controller like this @property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *places; Set identity name for your seque in storyboard

Then in source controller in method

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
   if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SegueName"])
   {
     YourDestinationVC *vc = (YourDestinationVC *)segue.destinationViewController;
     vc.places = places;

   }
}
```

Comment: how can display image from nsarray to uiimage view

Comment: UIImage *img = (UIImage *)images[0]; For the first one for example. And use in any place in view controller